# explain how JobLauncherApplicationRunner class works?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I was reading the source code of [`JobLauncherApplicationRunner`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java). according to my understanding when we use `Spring boot` + `Spring batch`, this class is used to find all the jobs in the application context and use `SimpleJobLauncher` to execute jobs in startup. I found some cases that contradicts my previous knowledge and if you help me out I will be grateful

1. I found no sign in `JobLauncherApplicationRunner` that this class is a spring managed bean, then why/how this class uses `@Autowired`?
2. This class implements  `ApplicationRunner` interface, again `Spring boot` finds all beans, and after application context refreshed, it will executes the `run` method of this interface for those beans that implemented this interface. how spring registers `JobLauncherApplicationRunner`?

Comment: It is created in the `BatchAutoConfiguration` class.

Comment: @M.Deinum you are a legend! if you want post your answer and I will accept that as answer thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is created as part of the auto configuration of Spring Batch. This auto configuration can be found in the [`BatchAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration.java#L73) class.

Here it will, conditionally, create an instance of the `JobLauncherApplicationRunner`.